# C言語　直線状の線分の重複回数を求めるアルゴリズム

Tags: c, アルゴリズム

x軸上にいくつかの線分があり、その線分の重なる数の最も大きい値を求める方法がわかりません。どのようなアルゴリズムで求めればいいのでしょうか？

**例**
・線分1の範囲(2<=x<=5)
・線分2の範囲(3<=x<=9)
・線分3の範囲(4<=x<=11)
 の場合、

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

2<=x<=3, 9<=x<=11 の範囲で1回重複
3<=x<=4, 5<=x<=9 の範囲で2回重複
4<=x<=5 の範囲で3回重複
になります。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

数直線の左から右へ線分を探していったとき、線分の左の端が現れた時に重なりが増え、右の端が現れた時に重なりが減ることを利用します。

具体的には、線分の端点のデータを集めてソートし、順番に走査して、左端だったら重なりを一つ増やし、右端だったら一つ減らして、重なりを求めます。サンプルコードは

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// 端点
struct end_t {
    double x;
    bool isLeft;
};

// 端点の比較
int compEnds(const void * p1, const void * p2) {
    const struct end_t * const pe1 = p1;
    const struct end_t * const pe2 = p2;

    if (pe1->x < pe2->x)
        return -1;
    if (pe1->x > pe2->x)
        return 1;

    // 線分の右端と別の線分の左端がおなじ座標の場合は
    // 線分は重なっていないものとする。
    if (pe1->isLeft && !pe2->isLeft)
        return 1;
    if (!pe1->isLeft && pe2->isLeft)
        return -1;

    return 0;
}

// 線分
struct segment_t {
    double left;
    double right;
};

// 線分のデータ
#define NUM_SEGMENTS (3)
struct segment_t Segments[NUM_SEGMENTS] = {
    { 2.0, 5.0 },
    { 3.0, 9.0 },
    { 4.0, 11.0 },
};

int main() {
    // 端点データのセットアップ
    struct end_t ends[NUM_SEGMENTS * 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_SEGMENTS; ++i) {
        ends[2 * i].x = Segments[i].left;
        ends[2 * i].isLeft = true;
        ends[2 * i + 1].x = Segments[i].right;
        ends[2 * i + 1].isLeft = false;
    }

    // 端点データのソート
    qsort(ends, NUM_SEGMENTS * 2, sizeof(struct end_t), compEnds);

    //　重なりを求める
    int maxOverlaps = 0;
    int currentOverlaps = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_SEGMENTS * 2; ++i) {
        if (ends[i].isLeft) {
            ++currentOverlaps;
            if (currentOverlaps > maxOverlaps)
                maxOverlaps = currentOverlaps;
        }
        else {
            --currentOverlaps;
        }
    }

    printf("Max overlaps: %d\n", maxOverlaps);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: なるほど！その手法だと線分の左端と右端を監視するだけで、重なりのカウントができるわけなんですね！ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 2):

C 言語だときついな・・。

### 単純な方法

線の数：N
開始点と終了を重複なく小さい順に並び替えます。(A)
線分の開始点、終了点 が それぞれ どの位置にあるかを2次元配列を作成します。(X[2*N][2*N])
i番目の線分の開始点と終了点の位置を x[i][bj] から x[i][ej] まで 1 で満たします。

この時のイメージ

```
線１：　2 -- 5
線２：　3 -- 9
線３：　4 -- 11

A[] 2, 3, 4 , 5, 9 , 11
線１： 0 - 4  （開始点０、終了点４）
線２： 1 - 5　
線３： 2 - 6

A[]      2, 3, 4 , 5, 9 , 11
　　　　----------------------
         0  1  2  3  4  5  6
　　　　----------------------
x[0][] : 1, 1 , 1, 1, 1, 0, 0
x[1][] : 0, 1 , 1, 1, 1, 1, 0
x[2][] : 0, 0 , 1, 1, 1, 1, 1
```

ここまでできれば、あとは x の 縦方向に 最大の個数を数えれば答えが出ます。

### より高度な方法

上記のアルゴリズムには一時作業領域が最大でも 4*N*N の領域が必要で
Nが大量にある場合にメモリ不足になる可能性があります。

最大の 重複回数**だけ**を求める事が要求されているのであれば
線分を 開始純に並べたリストと、終了点順に並べたリストと
すべての点を重複なく並び替えたリストを準備します。
そして今の点で重なっている線を格納するリストを準備します。
そして点の小さい順に、
この点から 線が始まった時は、重なった線を入れるリストに追加
この点で 線が終了した場合には 重なった線のリストから線を取り除く
ループを作って このループの中の最大の リストの件数を答えとします。

こうすると利用するメモリは N の数倍程度で、並び替えを事前に行う事で
終了点検索 検索のため O (N log N) 程度の時間で済むようになるはずです。

※ どこかの 競技プログラミングの 練習問題のようなきがしますが・・

### 追記

上記の方法では すべての線が重なるような場合に 処理時間と利用時間が増加します。
線をリストに保持する事はしなくても 同じ答えが出せることに気づけば
Hideki さんの回答が 最適な回答になると思います。

ただし、問題文の中にあいまいな仕様があるため、正しい答えは仕様によって
違うと思います。
線の開始と終了が一緒の場合があるか？
線の 終了点と 別の線の開始点が 同じ点の場合に 重なっていると判断するか？

これによって 重なりの個数の計算方法は変わります。

Comment: なるほど、各線分の配列に開始点から終了点までの位置に1を格納させ、最後にそれぞれの重なりを見ていくという手法なんですね！多角的な手法を身に付けることができ大変満足しております。

Answer (score 1):

整数あつかいのみで良いなら、重複回数を記録する配列を用意すれば
それほど手間をかけずにできそうです。
具体的なコードがないので疑似的コードでしめすと以下のようなイメージです。
いかがでしょう。

```
void f_Foo()
{
    int   重複回数サマリー[12];// 全て0に初期化する

    f_重複回数検査( 重複回数サマリー, 線分1);
    f_重複回数検査( 重複回数サマリー, 線分2);
    f_重複回数検査( 重複回数サマリー, 線分3);
    // 以上で各線分の重なり回数が、重複回数サマリー[n]にセットアップされたはず。
    // printするなりして確認しましょう。
}

void   f_重複回数検査(
   int *        サマリー配列,// (out)
   線分         対象線分)    // (in)
{
    int i;
   for( i = 対象線分.開始位置 ; i<対象線分.終了位置 ; i++){//終了位置を含まない
      サマリー配列[ i] += 1;
   }
}
```

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。整数あつかいのみについて、それぞれの整数位置でカウントすることによって求めるというのは理解できました。小数も考慮に入れると、どのようになるでしょうか。

Comment: Xが実数の場合は区切りがないので「重複回数サマリーの配列」の考えは使用できません。代替として「線分同士が重なる範囲の線分」という概念を導入せざるをえないかと考えます。関数の合算と積分と考えることができ、色々な解決方法があると考えられます。最終的な手法の決定は仕様に依存するのではないでしょうか。

Comment: 「線分同士が重なる範囲の線分」という概念を考慮に入れつつ、手法を考えていきたいと思います。アドバイスいただきありがとうございます。